# CSS picture and paragraph align with float , ugly layout when multiple entry added

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, alignment

I'm trying to place a picture on left , and explanation paragraph on the right side , it might be long to exceed the height of that image.

So i put out a minimal test case:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> This is an demo </title>
        <style>
            img { float: left; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <img src="61add42atw1dnf1k4h4qzj.jpg" />
            <p> This is a pretty long paragraph .. This is a pretty long paragraph .. This is a pretty long paragraph ..  This is a pretty long paragraph .. This is a pretty long paragraph .. This is a pretty long paragraph ..  This is a pretty long paragraph .. This is a pretty long paragraph .. This is a pretty long paragraph .. 
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <img src="61add42atw1dnf1k4h4qzj.jpg" />
            <p> This is a pretty long paragraph .. This is a pretty long paragraph .. This is a pretty long paragraph ..  This is a pretty long paragraph .. This is a pretty long paragraph .. This is a pretty long paragraph ..  This is a pretty long paragraph .. This is a pretty long paragraph .. This is a pretty long paragraph .. 
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the result (Chromium Browser 15) was totally bad:

[image]

The second `div` overlapped the first one.

P.S: i tried to use a HTML table , but that's not what i wanted , it's better fix my mistake here

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a clear:both to the content `div`, that way they won't overlap each other.

```
#content {
clear:both;
}
```

Also, if you are using #content multiple times you should use a `class` instead of an `id`. On classes and ids: http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php

Answer (score 0):

place a div between the content div `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` like

```
<div id="content"></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```